# Как перенести данные из одной таблицы в другую? sqlite

Tags: python, sqlite

У меня есть две таблицы:

```
# Активные задачи
cur.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS taskActive(
    ID TEXT,
    name TEXT, 
    description TEXT, 
    time TEXT
)""")
con.commit()

# Завершённые задачи
cur.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS taskDeleted(
    ID TEXT,
    name TEXT, 
    description TEXT, 
    time TEXT,
    timeDeleted TEXT
)""")
con.commit()
```

Как перенести данные из одной таблицы(например из taskActive) в другую(в taskDeleted)?

Comment: Через insert с select. Но почему бы не хранить в одной таблице, добавьте поле статус задачи. Представьте, что у вас появится еще статус, типа Paused, не делать ведь из-за этого еще одну сущность? :)

Comment: @gil9red Верно, так было бы легче, но оно бы попадало и в вывод. Я же хочу сделать это отдельно

Comment: https://sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html попробуйте использовать тригеры

Comment: Или, возможно, Вам подойдет конструкция `WITH` https://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html

Comment: @Артем `...но оно бы попадало и в вывод` а что мешает использовать `where not`?

Comment: @Артем, для фильтрации в выводе нужно добавлять фильтрация в select, типа получить все активные: `select * from task where status = 'Active'`

Comment: @gil9red Это логично! Главное работает. Оставьте ответ, отмечу его как верный

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы рекомендовал хранить все задачи в одной таблице:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS task(
    ID TEXT,
    name TEXT, 
    description TEXT, 
    time TEXT,
    timeDeleted TEXT,
    status TEXT
)
```

Где, статус может иметь значения `Active` или `Deleted`

Тогда, например, для выборки активных задач будет такое условие:

```sql
select * from task where status = 'Active'
```

Comment: Если всё в одной таблице, и статусов всего два - то поле статуса как бы лишнее... достаточно проверять на NULL поле `timeDeleted`.

Comment: @Akina, угу, но мне кажется, это похоже на костыль :)

Comment: Да вроде ничего костыльного-то нету - ну при условии, что статусов реально два, и третьего не видать даже в дальней прешпективе. Просто представь, что поле определено как `status TEXT GENERATED ALWAYS AS (CASE WHEN timeDeleted  IS NULL THEN 'Active' ELSE 'Deleted' END) VIRTUAL`. Что поменяется? ну кроме отсутствия необходимости и вообще невозможности в это поле записывать? да ничего! с точки зрения получения информации. Чутка проиграем по процессору, но выиграем по пространству (а если объявить как STORED, то по этим характеристикам вообще один в один).

Comment: @Akina, согласен с вашей позицией :)